STM32f411CE (Blackpill baord and MPU6050 sensor
I am trying to make a simple balancing function to balance 4 motors which are attached to the 4 channels of Tim3 on the STM32F411.
I have a sensor such as the mpu6050.
I have tried many "libraries" but i cant seem to get it to work.I just need something less complicated. Or just to give me guidelines where to start.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.
